# Is there a countifs format in panda dataframe without restructure the data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data and I would like to count the occurrence of 'Bad' for a same number, and the result should show the count of 'Bad' in a new column, which is same function the COUNTIFS excel formula **=COUNTIFS(N:N,N2,O:O,"Bad")**
[image: example of the result]

I have try to use the code below:

```
countbad = df.groupby('No')['Status'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')

df['CountBad'] = countbad('count')
```

but the result I get is include counting based on Good/Moderate as well.

[image: result got from the codes]

Is there any way to made the 'Bad' as the condition to count the number of occurrence and get exactly what I needed without changing the dataframe structure?

Thanks

Comment: kindly post a reproducible example. see [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with `Bad` for mask and convert to numeric `0,1` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) or [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) and then count values by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column with `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'No':list('aabbccd'),
         'Status':['Bad', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good', 'Bad'],

})

df['CountBad'] = df['Status'].eq('Bad').astype(int).groupby(df['No']).transform('sum')
#alternative
df['CountBad'] = df['Status'].eq('Bad').view('i1').groupby(df['No']).transform('sum')
print (df)

  No Status  CountBad
0  a    Bad         1
1  a   Good         1
2  b    Bad         2
3  b    Bad         2
4  c   Good         0
5  c   Good         0
6  d    Bad         1
```

Your solution is possible by reshape with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('No')['Status'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

And then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['CountBad'] = df['No'].map(df1['Bad'])
```

If want all counts columns use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df2 = df.join(df1.add_prefix('Count'), on='No')
print (df2)
  No Status  CountBad  CountGood
0  a    Bad         1          1
1  a   Good         1          1
2  b    Bad         2          0
3  b    Bad         2          0
4  c   Good         0          2
5  c   Good         0          2
6  d    Bad         1          0
```

Comment: can i know how to modify if i would like to count O2 as condition for row 2, the O3 for row 3 and so on? same as the excel formula:  ```=COUNTIFS(N:N,N2,O:O,O2)```

Comment: @BBBBBBBB - Sorry, what it means? How should be changed `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'No':list('aabbccd'),
         'Status':['Bad', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good', 'Bad'],

})` if applied `=COUNTIFS(N:N,N2,O:O,O2)` ? thanks.

Comment: kinda different: ```df = pd.DataFrame({'Al': list('aabccdd'),'Status': ['Bad','Good','ok','Bad','good','ok','ok']```  result will be ```Count: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2```, meaning count Status in status based on count in Al in Al, something like that, sorry if it is confusing, thanks

Comment: @BBBBBBBB - do you think `df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Al', 'Status'])['Status'].transform('size')` ?

Comment: it works, i did not think of using .transform('size'), thanks